# Can StringTemplate iterate through 'values' in a String?

Tags: java, templates, loops, stringtemplate

I have a String made up of several Strings seperated by commas.  Using StringTemplate, is there an easy way to write a seperate line for each 'value' in this outer String?

For example, I have:

```
String layers = "ADM,NAV";
```

and I want to output:

```
ADM,Y,
NAV,Y,
```

I suspect the template would look (if it's possible) something like this:

```
$layers.split(","): {layer | $layer$,Y, }$
```

Here's a somewhat-possibly related example I found of how write a line for each object in a collection:

```
<ul>
    $orders: {order|
        <li>Order $order.OrderId$</li>
    }$
</ul>
```

However, I *cannot* just build a collection out of the String in my Java code - it *must* remain a comma-seperated String.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible according to the [philosophy](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ST/Introduction#Introduction-MotivationAndPhilosophy) of StringTemplate: template engine's purpose is to separate representation from business logic. In your case splitting string is business logic and cannot be performed in template.